# Why is <link /> tag called link?

Tags: html, stylesheet

I Was wondering why is `<link />` tag in HTML is called `link`. Why not call it something like `<include />` as it includes things such as stylesheets? What does the word `link` actually signify? Why was `link` used?

Comment: Because you're `link`ing to an external file? It could be called whatever the creator liked, and `<link>` obviously made more sense to the creators than `<include>` (probably in an attempt to avoid confusion with PHP, JSP and Android, which all have an `include`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-link-element):

> The `link` element allows authors to *link* their document to other resources.

It's used to *link* to other resources. It's used to describe and specify a **relationship** between the document and another resource *which may be a stylesheet*, it's not necessarily importing a resource. The name `include` would entail that you're including a script or stylesheet, but that's not what `link` necessarily does.

Comment: hmmm, I am not sure. [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp) says link is defined as "Imports a style sheet". So it does not read well "link the imported stylesheet" rather than, "include the imported stylesheet"

Comment: @user123 Please don't rely on W3Schools, it's known for bad explanations. `link` doesn't just import the stylesheet, it links the stylesheet to the main document as a resource for the document to use. `link`s aren't just used for stylesheets, either.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  That makes complete sense now.  I have just read the actually W3 reference and reported the error to W3Schools -----> A "stylesheet" link does not actually "Import a style sheet".  It actually just "links it".  The css is not "imported" into the html source, rather, it is linked via a reference to another file which contains the styles as [W3's reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-stylesheet)